# Strange delays of Twisted-based socket-server (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, tcp, twisted

My project is a socket server for interacting with remote hardware. 
Basically it does 2 things:

1) Collection and processing of telematics packages sent by the remote hardware

2) Transfer of commands received via external API

We are using Python3 along with Twisted + MongoDB as a storage.

There are two entities working with twisted:

- DeviceProtocol that handles permanent connections to remote hardware devices
- HelperProtocol that acts as a broker between the API and the HardwareProtocol (receives commands from API via local TCP, and transfer to DeviceProtocol via Fabric Class)

Code example

```
class DeviceProtocol(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory


    def connectionMade(self):
        """
        Change object status in DB
        Set to objects collection in Factory
        """

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        """
        Change object status in DB
        Del from objects collection in Factory
        """

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        recv_def = defer.Deferred()
        recv_def.addCallback(self.pasre_data)
        recv_def.addErrback(self.log_error)
        recv_def.callback(data)

    def log_error(self, data):
        self.log.warning("Something happens, %s", data)

    def parse_data(self, data):
        """
        Calculate response and call def send_data()
        Some manipulations with data
        """

    def send_data(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)



class HelperProtocol(Protocol):

    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory


    def connectionMade(self):
        self.log.info("CONNECTION FROM API")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.data = json.loads(data.decode('utf-8'))
        remote_device = self.data['remote_device']
        data_pack = self.data['data_pack']
        self.factory.objects[remote_device].send_data(data_pack) # send data to remote device
        self.transport.write('ok'.encode('utf-8')) # send ok response to remote API service


    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.log.info("API CONNECTION TERMINATED")



class ProtocolFactory(Factory):
    objects = {}

    def __init__(self, type):
        self.clients = {}
        self.type = type

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        if self.type == "device":
            return DeviceProtocol(self)
        if self.type == "api":
            return HelperProtocol(self)


endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, port, interface)
endpoint.listen(ProtocolFactory("device"))

endpoint_api = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, another_port, interface)
endpoint_api.listen(ProtocolFactory("api"))

reactor.run()
```

The actual problem
First test with 50 devices(DeviceProtocol) and 10(HelperProtocol) simultaneous connections to a helper got a perfect result without any delays. 
When we added 20 more devices, the system has gone nuts:

- API receives the data and passes it to the helper over tcp connection
- Helper get event connectionMade after one minute and dataReceived event one more minute later (it was only a couple of milliseconds with 50 devices)
- Helper through the factory sends the command to the DeviceProtocol

Server’s 1.5 GHz core is loaded by 1 - 1.2%, there is no consumption of RAM either.

What’s going on, guys?

Comment: Can you post an SSCCE?  http://sscce.org/

Comment: How much time does it take to parse the received data? It's very common to have blocking tasks which takes "some time" (eg. anything more than 5) and delay other parts of the code from running until all the blocking tasks are complete. In general you want to use a producer/consumer architecture for ingesting data or use buffers. But we need more details to truly answer your question.